# NameError: name 'urllib' is not defined TypeError:'module' object not callable

Tags: python, url, raspberry-pi3

Trying to execute this code. But i get the above error.

```
from urllib.request import FancyURLopener
from urllib.request import urlopen
exam = urllib.request.urlopen("192.168.2.2")
    print(exam.read)
    exam.close()
```

I expect to open the provided IP address.

Comment: Simply use `urlopen` instead of `urllib.request.urlopen` as you have already imported it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from urllib.request import FancyURLopener
from urllib.request import urlopen
exam = urlopen("http://192.168.2.2")
print(exam.read)
exam.close()
```

Try using `urlopen("url")` rather than the full `urllib.request.urlopen(url)`.

You need to add http or https on your URL to make this work. Also, check out python `requests`, a good alternative to `urllib`.